# How do I work with two endpoints using the JetBrains GraphQL plugin?

Tags: graphql, jetbrains-ide

Currently I'm using something like the following in PyCharm using the [GraphQL plugin for JetBrains IDEs](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8097-js-graphql) to work with two different GraphQL endpoints that I switch between in my work (a local and a remote), with the consequence that I (need to manually) overwrite the schema file when I switch between them.

Is there a way to do this with a different schema file for each endpoint? What is the correct idiom for working with (and switching between) two endpoints?

```
{
  "name": "My Schema",
  "schemaPath": "_schema.graphql",
  "extensions": {
    "endpoints": {
      "Local GraphQL Endpoint": {
        "url": "http://localhost:5000",
        "headers": {
          "user-agent": "JS GraphQL"
        },
        "introspect": true
      },
      "Remote GraphQL Endpoint": {
        "url": "http://my.remote.io",
        "headers": {
          "user-agent": "JS GraphQL"
        },
        "introspect": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: *"...using the JetBrains GraphQL plugin..."* This is 3rd party plugin and not made by JetBrains. Please contact plugin author about that -- https://github.com/jimkyndemeyer/js-graphql-intellij-plugin/issues/ Also check https://jimkyndemeyer.github.io/js-graphql-intellij-plugin/docs/developer-guide

Comment: @LazyOne Clarified. Already contacted. Already consulted.